# FetchXML to sort Activity based on Activity status Text

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I need a fetchXML that can sort all activities based on Activity Status option set Text.

My FetchXML

```
<fetch top='5000' >
  <entity name='task' >
    <attribute name='activityid' />
    <attribute name='statecode' />
    <attribute name='statuscodename' />
    <order attribute='statecode' />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It is sorting on the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the order to use the name of the option set value:

```
<fetch top='5000' >
  <entity name='task'>
    <attribute name='activityid' />
    <attribute name='statecode' />
    <attribute name='statecodename' />
    <attribute name='statuscodename' />
    <order attribute='statecodename' />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @Aron, I was adding this field as an attribute but did not tried adding this name attribute for sorting. Now It is doing the expected work.